# MongoDB - Find records which doesn't have parent document reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I'm trying to make a group wise alert, where users get alerts when they access the `node.js` website by cloning the actual document for storing individual alert view status. The basic sample data for the *alerts collection* is as follows.

```
db.alerts.insertMany([
  {
    "text" : "Alert 1",
  },
  {
    "text" : "Alert 2",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ba8e5ef24e03456b5cb0afa"),
    "text" : "Alert 3",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ba8e5ef24f03456b5cb0afa"),
    "text": "Alert 4"
  },
  {
    "text": "Alert 4",
    "master_id": ObjectId("5ba8e5ef24f03456b5cb0afa"),
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "Alert 3",
    "master_id": ObjectId("5ba8e5ef24e03456b5cb0afa"),
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "Alert 4",
    "master_id": ObjectId("5ba8e5ef24f03456b5cb0afa"),
    "user_id": 2
  },
]);
```

If I use `$lookup`, I can get documents which doesn't have child documents, by executing following

```
db.getCollection('alerts').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "alerts",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "master_id",
            as: "related_record"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "master_id": null,
            "related_record": {$eq: []}
        },
    }
]);
```

However, if I have to get specific to `user_id: 1`, what should I pass additionally? Or how should I restructure it?

Comment: Could you explain what you really want  to do

Comment: As per @mathpen 's answer, I get master documents which user_id 1 has got. But I want to find out master records, which user_id 1 hasn't got. Its clear that user 1 hasn't got alert 1 & 2, and user 2 has only alert 4. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change you match stage with the following :

```
...,
$match:
{
  "master_id": null,
  "related_record.user_id": 1
}
```

Comment: With this solution, I get master documents which user_id 1 has got. But I want to find out master records, which user_id 1 hasn't got. Its clear that user 1 hasn't got alert 1 & 2, and user 2 has only alert 4. This is the result I'm looking for.